# Show specific content based on 4 drop-down selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I've managed to source some code to achieve the above, however, despite several attempts, I cannot get it to work. Could anyone please assist me on this?

JS in HEAD of HTML file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(function($){

        selects = $('#select-container select'),
        results = $('#results-container > div');

        selects.change(function(){        
        var values = '';
        selects.each(function(){
            values += '.' + $(this).val();
        });        
        results.filter(values).show().siblings().hide();
        });

        });
    </script>
```

HTML in BODY of HTML file:

```
<div class="margins1"><h2>Goal</h2>
    <div id='select-container'>
<select>
<option value='none'>Select Option</option>
    <option value='Fat Loss'>Fat Loss</option>
    <option value='Lean Muscle'>Lean Muscle</option>
    <option value='Size & Mass'>Size & Mass</option>
    </select>
    <h2>Dietary Requirements</h2>
    <select>
    <option value='none'>Select Option</option>
        <option value='No Requirements'>No Requirements</option>
    <option value='Vegetarian'>Vegetarian</option>
    <option value='Vegan'>Vegan</option>
        <option value='Gluten Free'>Gluten Free</option>
            <option value='Gluten Free (vegetarian)'>Gluten Free (vegetarian)</option>
                <option value='Gluten Free'>Gluten Free (vegan)</option>
                    <option value='Dairy Free'>Dairy Free</option>
                        <option value='Dairy Free (vegetarian)'>Dairy Free (vegetarian)</option>
                        <option value='Dairy Free (vegan)'>Dairy Free (vegan)</option>
                        <option value='Nut Free'>Nut Free</option>
                                                <option value='Nut Free (vegetarian)'>Nut Free (vegetarian)</option>
                                                                        <option value='Nut Free (vegan)'>Nut Free (vegan)</option>
                                                                        <option value='Supplement Free'>Supplement Free</option>
                                                                        <option value='Supplement Free (vegetarian)'>Supplement Free (vegetarian)</option>
                                                                        <option value='Supplment Free (vegan)'>Supplement Free (vegan)</option>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                        <h2>Type of Day</h2>
                                                                        <select>
                                                                        <option value='none'>Select Option</option>
        <option value='Non-Back-Load Day (10-Day Prep/CNS)'>Non-Back-Load Day (10-Day Prep/CNS)</option>
    <option value='Back-Load Day (10-Day Prep/CNS)'>Back-Load Day (10-Day Prep/CNS)</option>
    <option value='Non-Back-Load Day (CBL)'>Non-Back-Load Day (CBL)</option>
    <option value='Back-Load Day (CBL)'>Back-Load Day (CBL)</option>
    </select>
    <h2>Cooking Level</h2>
    <select>
    <option value='none'>Select Option</option>
        <option value='Minimal Cooking'>Minimal Cooking</option>
    <option value='Moderate Cooking'>Moderate Cooking</option>
    <option value='Maximum Cooking'>Maximum Cooking</option>
    </select></br>

</div>
```

Here is the rest of the HTML code that assigns combinations of drop-down selections to a piece of text. I have only done one example:

```
    <div class="margins2"><h1>Meal Plan...</h1>
<div id='results-container'>
<div class='Fat Loss No Requirements Back-Load Day (CBL) Moderate Cooking'> IT WORKS</div>
  </div>
```

The second div class has 4 inputs. It looks strange without commas or separate '' marks but the tutorial doesn't include these and it works. Finally, here is some code from my EXTERNAL CSS file:

```
#results-container > div { display: none; }
```

Can anyone please assist me in fixing the issue of no text displaying or identify why this is happening? The JSFiddle link of the tutorial of what I want to achieve can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/chnZP/

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in how the values in the drop-down lists are written. Because values are directly used as class names you are restricted in your choice of special characters.

Following the tutorial example, if you select `alpha`, `blue` and `dog` the script will turn this into a string `".alpha.blue.dog"` and then select the elements containing those 3 class names using the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

Because the string is sent to jQuery to manage it has to follow a strict syntax. This means you cannot using spaces, backslashes, parentheses (...and so on) in your class names because they will be parsed differently.

Editing the code slightly will fix it. http://jsfiddle.net/AjdHa/7/

```
<div id='select-container'>
    <select>
        <option value='none'>Select Option</option>
        <option value='Fat_Loss'>Fat Loss</option>
    </select>
    <h2>Dietary Requirements</h2>

    <select>
        <option value='none'>Select Option</option>
        <option value='No_Requirements'>No Requirements</option>
    </select>
    <h2>Type_of_Day</h2>

    <select>
        <option value='none'>Select Option</option>
        <option value='Non-Back-Load_Day_CBL'>Non-Back-Load Day (CBL)</option>
    </select>
    <h2>Cooking Level</h2>

    <select>
        <option value='none'>Select Option</option>
        <option value='Minimal_Cooking'>Minimal Cooking</option>
        <option value='Moderate_Cooking'>Moderate Cooking</option>
        <option value='Maximum_Cooking'>Maximum Cooking</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="margins2">
    <h1>Meal Plan...</h1>
    <div id='results-container'>
        <div class='Fat_Loss No_Requirements Non-Back-Load_Day_CBL Moderate_Cooking'>
            IT WORKS
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. This works exactly how I want it to in your link provided, however, when applying it to my code it still doesn't work. I am not too sure why. Is there any way of me sending you my script without the use of JSFiddle? Once again your time is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not too sure why either. It might be how the class names are written in `results-container`? For example, it should be something like `class='Fat_Loss No_Requirements Back-Load_Day_CBL Moderate_Cooking'`, matching what you have in the drop-down lists.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Yep, I've checked this a dozen times and it matches, but no luck. Would you mind me sending over my code some how?

Comment: I've even created a test script using more or less exactly your implementation, but still no luck :-( - only thing I did was remove the underscores and made the names CamelCase. re you referencing the Javascript externally or including it on your <head></head> tags? Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to include the jQuery library if it isn't already. Does any error show up? Using tools depending on your browser it might reveal helpful bits of information.

Comment: Also, enclose your script inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` to make sure everything is loaded before running it.

Comment: It was the addition of the jQuery library! Thank you so much!